# C# Merge 2 Json Strings

Tags: c#

I tried to merge 2 json strings but unfortunatly it doesn't work as expected because I'm looking to merge these 2 json data based on id as depicted here below :

```
Json_1 :
result [
        result[0]
              { id : 11111
                attribute1 : "<anything>"
                attribute2 : "<anything>"
                ...
              } 
        result[1]
              { id : 22222
                attribute1 : "<anything>"
                attribute2 : "<anything>"
                ...
              } 
        ...
      ]

Json_2 :
result [
        result[0]
              { id : 11111
                attribute99 : "<anything>"
                attribute98 : "<anything>"
                ...
              } 
        result[1]
              { id : 22222
                attribute99 : "<anything>"
                attribute98 : "<anything>"
                ...
              } 
        ...
]

Expect Merged Json should look like this :
Result[
           result[0]
              { id : 11111
                attribute1 : "<anything>"
                attribute2 : "<anything>"
                attribute99 : "<anything>"
                attribute98 : "<anything>"
                ...
              } 
        result[1]
              { id : 22222
                attribute1 : "<anything>"
                attribute2 : "<anything>"
                attribute99 : "<anything>"
                attribute98 : "<anything>"
                ...
              } 
        ...
]
```

Where attributes from Json_2 are merged with those of Json_2 according to the id of each result object in the array.

can someone help me with C# code of such Merge ?

UPDATE :

Thanks for the provided help. What I did so far is the function here below is to get json_2 nested in json_1 according to to each id. What I'm looking for is to get all keys,values appended to the json_1 properties. Knowing that I'm not a pur developer with limited expertise in C#.

```
    public static string MergeJson(string json1,string json2)
    {

        JObject obj_json_1 = JObject.Parse(json1);
        JObject obj_json_1 = JObject.Parse(json2);

        var lookup = obj_json_2.SelectTokens("result[*]").ToLookup(c => (string)c["id"]);

        foreach (var std in obj_json_1.SelectTokens("result[*]"))
        {
            try
            {
                std["result"] = (new JArray(lookup[(string)std["id"]]));
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error in Merge Json : {0}", e.Message);
            }
        }
        return obj_json_1.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Where is the code you need help with?

Comment: are you aware that your "JSON" is not even close to being valid JSON? also: what have you ***tried yourself***? what problems did you encounter? what have you researched?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to declare the JSON class like this:

```cs
class Result
{
    public List<Dictionary<string, string>> result
}
```

Then you can get the two objects with Newtonsoft.Json, like so:

```cs
var result = JsonConvert.Deserialize<Result>(jsonA)?.result ?? new List<Dictionary<string, string>>;
var other = JsonConvert.Deserialize<Result>(jsonB)?.result ?? new List<Dictionary<string, string>>;
```

Then you can merge them by going in series, remember that we may not have a particular index so we need to create the object there:

```cs
result.Capacity = Math.Max(result.Count, other.Count);   //for better performance, can remove
for(var i = 0; i < other.Count; i++)
{
    if(result.Count < i)
        result.Add(new Dictionary<string, string>());
    if(result[i] == null)
        result[i] = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    result[i].Capacity = result[i].Count + other[i].Count;   //for better performance, can remove
    for each(var kvp in other[i])
        result[i][kvp.Key] = kvp.Value;
}
```

`result` now contains the merged result.

**Note** We are making an assumption that there are no overlapping keys.